# increasing speed of sql update postgresql

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, database-performance

I'm performing the 2 below queries on my database, and I'm trying to figure out how to make it faster.
The first query takes 208796.8ms. The second one takes 611654.9ms. I'm not sure there is a way to make them faster. I need these updates to be in the same transaction, so I'm also not sure if the update by batches of n records would be faster. I will take any idea !

```
UPDATE ticket_memberships AS my_table
        SET ticket_id = foreign_table.id
        FROM tickets AS foreign_table
        WHERE my_table.agency_id = 2
        AND foreign_table.agency_id = 2
        AND my_table.ticket_id IS NOT NULL
        AND my_table.ticket_id = foreign_table.old_id

UPDATE ticket_memberships AS my_table
        SET person_contact_id = foreign_table.id
        FROM person_contacts AS foreign_table
        WHERE my_table.agency_id = 2
        AND foreign_table.agency_id = 2
        AND my_table.person_contact_id IS NOT NULL
        AND my_table.person_contact_id = foreign_table.old_id
```

Comment: How many records are in your table? Also when you update the table how many records are being updated? Do you have any triggers for this table on `Update`?

Comment: Append `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)` output if you want a meaningful answer.

Comment: Can you show the DDL for all three tables?